# Intermittent FluentNHibernate configuration Error

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

I use right now FluentNHibernate with in an application. The problem is that I sometimes receive the following error:

> "connect failed because target host or object does not exist oracle"

But after restarting Visual Studio and some "rebuilds" everything works just fine.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it dosen't. I don't understand what the problem could be. Maybe somebody had the same problem before? The inner exception is clear:

> ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

I understand the inner exception but it is weird that it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. And I'm tired to solved this always with: Restart my Visual Studio and rebuild, sometimes I restart my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use config file as a place to store server name?
Check them.Besides, I had the same issue when I had two projects in my solution, each with seperate config file with the same name (two executables), and they were building in the same output folder. So when you build 1-st one, his config is copied to the ouput, the same with the second one. Or even worse: you run 1-st one, it builds, copying config to the output, then the 2-nd one builds, and his config is copied to the output, so as a result you are running 1-st project with the 2-nd config.
In that case you just need to configure your building order, or use seperate Outputs.

Actually it could be anything, this is only the example I've seen. Check this case, and if it isn't the right one - provide some more info.

**Upd:** Also check your real config from the Output folder, not the one that is in the solution

Comment: i will check, yes i have 3 projects : first my client (noHibernate there ) a Commons proyect where a have models and stuff, and my third a server (where i have my hibernate stuff) , i work with WCF services, i will look in that configuration, maybe can be that.

Thanks!!!